# Accessing constants inside PHP object

Tags: php, class, properties

Currently I'm reading PHP 5 OOP ([properties section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)) and there I found the following statement:

> Within class methods the properties, *constants*, and methods may be
>   accessed by using the form $this->property

That's strange, but I can't access constants using that format. Following code will raise notice:

```
class A
{
    const HELLO = 'HELLO WORLD';

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->HELLO;
    }
}

$a = new A();
```

Did I misunderstand something or authors of documentation made a mistake?

Comment: @NullUserException:  Class constants are not static properties, and he's not accessing it from within a static method.

Comment: @drrcknlsn You are technically correct, but the page does tell you there are two ways to access properties, depending on what they are (`$this->` and `self::`). My guess is whoever wrote the docs felt constants closely resembled static properties and left the "constants" part out of the sentence.

Comment: Please see the class constants manual page: http://php.net/language.oop5.constants . The object properties page was misleading and actually not really about constants.

Comment: @NullUserException:  You don't use a sigil when accessing constants as you do for static properties, so it's more than just a semantic difference - `self::FOO` vs. `self::$foo`.

Answer (score 4):

to access the constant try

```
class A
{
    const HELLO = 'HELLO WORLD';

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo self::HELLO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that. I want the explanation of statement from official PHP documentation.

Comment: ok: constants don't depends on instances, their value is "constant", so they have to be called in static way (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). The notation `$this->varname` means any changeable variable of your current instance.

Answer (score 2):

The entry in the manual was a bit misleading indeed. I have removed the references to constants and methods now, because they don't belong into a chapter about properties anyway. The new paragraph will sound something like this now:

> Within class methods non-static properties may be accessed by using -> (Object Operator): $this->property (where property is the name of the property). Static properties are accessed by using the :: (Double Colon): self::$property. See [Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for more information on the difference between static and non-static properties.

- http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=328166 and
- http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=328167

It may take up to a week until the changes appear on all mirrors.

Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Constants are accessed with `self` or with class name.
If you are in the same class:

```
self::HELLO
```

If you are using it in another class:

```
A::HELLO
```

Comment: I know that. I want the explanation of statement from official PHP documentation.

Comment: You can take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php But the information is not very good, I think. Couldn't find something better on the officional doc. Maybe you can take a look on some books, too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `self::HELLO` !!

Answer (score 0):

The clearest explanation of this is on the [Class Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) page of the PHP manual. From within a class, you access the constants using `self::constant`, from outside the class you use `Classname::constant` to access it.

For your example you would use:-

```
class A
{
    const HELLO = 'HELLO WORLD';

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo self::HELLO;
    }
}

$a = new A();
```

or, from outside the class:-

```
echo A::HELLO;
```

However, the explanation in the manual page I linked is excellent and very clear.

I should point out that there is no need to instantiate the class to access the constants contained in it. The following will work:-

```
class A
{
    const HELLO = 'HELLO WORLD';
}

echo A::HELLO;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class itself, you access a constant like you would a static: `self::MY_CONSTANT`, outside of the class, you refer to it by using `Class_Name::MY_CONSTANT`. When in doubt, (like, or example in abstract classes), I like to use:

```
$self = get_called_class($this);
$self::MY_CONSTANT;//gets the constant of currently called class
```

An easy way of remembering this: think of PDO query's:

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//<-- uses class constant
```